# How to resolve Windows Certificate app Supported "API test" test result fail

Tags: c#, c++, pdf, dll, windows-runtime

I have a windows store app and I am doing windows certificate test and it is going to fail in only one scenario that is "Supported API test"

the reason is I have updated "PDF Xpansion SDK (WinRT 8.1), Version 10" and SQLite 
it is saying like...

```
API ??0COMException@Platform@@QE$AAA@H@Z in vccorlib120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. pdf-xpansion-winrt.dll calls this API.
```

API ??0Delegate@Platform@@QE$AAA@XZ in vccorlib120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. pdf-xpansion-winrt.dll calls this API. 
API ??0DisconnectedException@Platform@@QE$AAA@XZ in vccorlib120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. pdf-xpansion-winrt.dll calls this API. 
API ??0InvalidArgumentException@Platform@@QE$AAA@XZ in vccorlib120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. pdf-xpansion-winrt.dll calls this API. 
API ??0NotImplementedException@Platform@@QE$AAA@XZ in vccorlib120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. pdf-xpansion-winrt.dll calls this API. 
API ??0NullReferenceException@Platform@@QE$AAA@XZ in vccorlib120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. pdf-xpansion-winrt.dll calls this API. 
API ??0Object@Platform@@QE$AAA@XZ in vccorlib120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. pdf-xpansion-winrt.dll calls this API. 
API ?AlignedFree@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAXPEAX@Z in vccorlib120_app.dll is not supported for this application type. pdf-xpansion-winrt.dll calls this API.

I don't know what is going to wrong here..

Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package for Windows(DLL)
versoin is "12.0.0.0"

and

SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1)(DLL)
version is "3.8.7.4"

but still it is failing this test, how to resolved this.
[image]
Thank you,
-Jitendra Jadav.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Windows Update KB2976978 installed, uninstall it, I had a similar issue, after uninstall the certification was a success.

Comment: I did same what you mention above but still not working same issue.:(

Comment: Did you also ignored this KB2976978  Update for upcoming Updates? Because if you dont then it will be reinstalled.  Anyway try to upload your App, this issue is just locally and won't harm your App Package / Certification